# Trying to use async to shorten computation time but failed... any tips?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have a function that looks for relationships 2 levels deep.
First, the function gets a company from the database and then looks for people related to it, then parses through the people to schedule `asyncio.create_task(async_func())` as such:

```py
async def get_company_related_data(self, bno: str, uuid: str = ""):
    people = []
    base_company = self.get_company_by_bno(bno, get_dict_objects=False)[0]

    people.extend(await base_company.get_related_people(convert_data=False))
    ...
    task_list = []
        for person in people:
            task_list.append(process_for_bubble_chart(person))
        results = await asyncio.gather(*task_list)
```

Here, the idea is to grab a company's related people first through the `base_company.get_related_people()` method. Once I've gotten those people, I iterate through those people and:

1 - Set up tasks to `process_for_bubble_chart()` so that they can run at the same time (there could be 20+ people and each of them could be related to multiple companies).

2 - I await ALL results (at least I think I am...) by inserting all tasks into the `asyncio.gather()` function.

3 - Below you can see I do the same thing for each person.

The `process_for_bubble_chart()` function:

```py
async def process_for_bubble_chart(person: GcisCompanyInfoPerson or GcisLimitedPartnerPerson, convert_to_data: bool = True):
    """
        Function that fetches related entities from the database
        based on the people objects within the 'people' list.
    """
    related_entities = []
    try:
        task_list = [
            person.get_related_companies(),
            person.get_related_businesses(),
            person.get_related_limited_partners(),
            person.get_related_factories(),
            person.get_related_stockcompanies()
        ]

        results = asyncio.gather(*task_list)
    except Exception as err:
        # Exception stuff
    else:
        for task_res in await results:
            related_entities.extend(task_res)

    if convert_to_data:
        data = person.to_relation_data_object()
        data.update({"related": related_entities})
        return data

    return related_entities
```

And the `get_related_XXX()` methods look like this (more or less the same code returning different objects):

```py
async def get_related_companies(self, exclude_bno: bool = True):
    sql = """
        SELECT * FROM Companies WHERE ...
        """
        # SQL fetch logic
        return [GcisCompanyInfo1(row) for row in query_db(sql)]
```

Where `query_db()` is just a wrapper function for querying the database.

Before I implemented async, the full queries took too long (~20 sec.) so I looked into how to use the asyncio module to make things go quicker, but the computation time stayed about the same (if not even slightly longer!).
How do I improve this?

This code runs as a FastAPI backend.

Comment: What part of this is asynchronous? There's nothing here to await

Comment: Could you simplify your code to reduce it to a minimal working example? These `print(Fore.RED, err, Style.RESET_ALL)` and similar are distracting and not necessary for the problem.

Comment: I’ve the same question as @CJR. It’s not clear from the code why do you think you should see improved performance. Which part of the code do you expect should run in parallel (assuming you’re running on a multicore machine)?

Comment: I've added some more comments to clarify the situation. I've clearly misunderstood the usage of asyncio's functions and the concepts behind async methods / coroutines...

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar: to be fair, Python has very little ability to take advantage of actual multicore machines, outside of C-level parallel code. async/await is more geared towards making concurrent programming with I/O easier, where `await`s generally block on I/O operations to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async` functions don't magically run in parallel - they only parallelize when you ultimately use `await` on some operation which waits for a specific event to occur (common examples are things like socket reads or timed sleeps). For example, if you have an async `query_db` function that can query the database asynchronously, then that may allow you to parallelize the operation.

In the absence of such an async operation, you may consider standard threads instead, using e.g. `asyncio.get_running_loop().run_in_executor(None, process_for_bubble_chart, person)` to run a *non-async* function in a thread.

Comment: Thank you so much for the comments! This cleared up a few things, but one question for me remains:
Does this mean that if I make the `query_db()` function `async` instead, this might actually work because it's now blocking the execution?

Comment: It depends on how `query_db` works. Ultimately, you need (usually) a blocking I/O operation. For example, with a database server, you would typically send the server a command, and then receive a response. If you `await` the response read, the event loop can parallelize that I/O. Just making `query_db` async won't solve anything unless the underlying I/O operations are also `async`.

Comment: Thanks for the insight!
I clearly have quite a few more things to learn before being able to correctly implement async.. I think I will try to revert to standard threads instead :)